# Linear Algebra: orthogonality in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

$$v_{1} = (1, 1, 1)$$

$$v_{2} = (-1, 1, 0)$$

$$v_{3} = (-1, -1, 2)$$

The vectors $v1$, $v2$, and $v3$ form an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

If $w = (4, -2, 4)$, then what is the coordinate vector, $[w]_{B}$, of $w$ with respect to the basis $B = {v1, v2, v3}$

Comment: Welcome to math.se. [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$$(4,-2,4)=w=av_1+bv_2+cv_3\implies \langle v_1,w\rangle = 3a_1$$

Can you now complete the deduction? Can you see why having an *orthonormal* basis makes things even easier than the above?

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: Where did the 3a1 come from?

Comment: ok so I think i know where you got 3a1 from.  did you just do the dot product of v1 with itself? Then repeated this to find b and c?

Comment: @bradp Yes, but with $\;v_2,v_3\;$ the dot product is zero...